# Use CKEditor CSS styling in normal div

Tags: css, ckeditor

Please see attached screenshots. Is there a way to create a div that shows the HTML snippet exactly as it was inside the CKEditor window? In my app, certain users enter in text using CKEditor, which other users need to see in view-only mode. Some of the simple styling is preserved (e.g. italics, bold) but other important styling elemenets (e.g. highlighting, table borders) are lost.

[image: EDIT MODE]

[image: VIEW MODE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest option will be to use CKEditor in the [read-only mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_readonly).

The reason why I recommend using entire CKEditor is that you can take the HTML that's inside it, but you would also need to get the same stylesheets and that won't be easy.

I guess that you may want to display the read-only content as if it isn't placed in an editor. For that you could use the [inline mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) or an editor without toolbar, elementspath and resize plugins. In the second case remember to [disable the ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf).

Comment: This is a really good answer... unfortunately our requirements for displaying the data doesn't permit a CKEditor window around it (even if disabled).

Comment: That's why I explained in my answer how to remove it.